# Randomly populate button in iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I am developing a simple game without using any of CA or Cocos2D stuff, In my app I am creating some fly object(UIButton with image) and moving it randomly on screen once the user touches any of these object i will just show another image and hides that object.

Now my problem is once the object gets hide i need to create it again say,
Once my app starts running

1. Initially say, 10 objects creates within 2 seconds, then
2. in another 2 seconds 20 objects has to be created like this continuously objects has to be created if user touches any object it needs to be disappear.
   How can i achieve this?

   **I mean how can i continuously populate objects?, do i need to allocate every time? or is there any way to reuse 1 single object?**
   Any help is appreciated in advance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

can't you move the hidden to next position and  show it when need?

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate an object every time, but your game might get slow and jittery because of the overhead involved in allocating and displaying a new UIButton and image.

It would be much more efficient to create an array of 40 or so UIButtons + images and reuse them. When the user touches one of them, set it to hidden. When you need to "create" a new one, just loop through your array looking for a hidden one. Make that one visible and put it at the new location and size.